# converting shared library to static library

Tags: shared-libraries, static-libraries

How can I convert a shared library to static library?
I'm trying to statically build valgrind, which requires the conversion of shared objects into static libraries. Normal build procedure of valgrind creates few shared libraries. Is there any way to convert these shared libraries(.so) to static library?

Comment: I think it is technically possible. We need to scan code in order to find references to PLT and recreate relocation table. However, I don't know any tool to do this easily.

Comment: @JérômePouiller If you consider a simpler case where the shared library itself has no other dynamic dependencies, then it seems easy to reconstruct the relocation table: Static analysis on the binary (similar to what IDA does) can give you the list of referenced symbols and locations, so that should suffice. Am I missing something, or is the only reason why no one has created a tool for this is that it's pointless.

Comment: @1110101001 I share your opinion. It seems it is not difficult to do, but nobody need it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's feasible that you might be able to do this. But since you can just build a static library rather than a shared library, I don't imagine you will find a tool to convert.